# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, function, methods, undefined, call

Here I import the files.class.php class which contains the getAllFiles() function:

```
include_once('lib/files.class.php');
```

Here I am calling the function :

```
<?php 
  $files = new Files($db);
  $jsonEncoding = json_encode($files->getAllFiles());
  $jsonFile = fopen("jsonEncoded.json", "w") or die ("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($jsonFile, $jsonEncoding);
  $contentOfFile = file_get_contents('./jsonEncoded.json');
  echo $contentOfFile;
  fclose($jsonFile);
?>
```

This is the getAllFiles() function :

```
public function getAllFiles() {
        if (!($stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, Name, Radius FROM Files"))) {
            $this->lastError = 'Failed to prepare query: ('.$this->connection->errno.') '.$this->connection->error;
            return false;
        } else {
            // Execute the query and store the result set
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

        // Bind the results to variables
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $latitude, $longitude, $name, $radius);
        $results = array();
        // Keep fetching rows
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
          // Add to array
            $results[] = array(
                'ID' => $id,
                'Latitude' => $latitude,
                'Longitude' => $longitude,
                'Name' => $name,
                'Radius' => $radius,
            );
          }
          // Return the results array
          return $results;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Files::getAllFiles() in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mbax4cl3/groupproject/map.php on line 83**

Thank you !

Comment: What is on line 83?  I'm betting an undefined function.

Comment: confirm that this method is actually inside a class called Files ?

Comment: The method is in a class called Files , im sure of that.

Comment: this is on line 83: $jsonEncoding = json_encode($files->getAllFiles());

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($files);` ?

Comment: Solved the problem , thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it doesn't make any sense , the problem seems to be with the code after this line :  $jsonEncoding = json_encode($files->getAllFiles());
However, the error occurs on that line.

I changed the code to the following and it works fine :

```
    <?php 
  $files = new Files($db);
  $jsonEncoding = json_encode($files->getAllFiles());
  print_r($jsonEncoding);
?>
```

Thank you !